# Is this a Boolean algebra? (proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Let $B=\{0,1\}$ and the binary operations $\oplus,\cdot$

We define a **bijection** $\varphi$ s.t.:

$$
\varphi:B \longrightarrow L=\{\mathbf{False},\mathbf{True}\},
$$
$$
\varphi(x):=
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{True}, \quad x=1 \\
\mathbf{False}, \quad x=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
In addition, it satisfies
$$
\varphi(a \oplus b)=\varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b)
$$
$$
\varphi(a \cdot b)=\varphi(a) \land \varphi(b)
$$
Thus, $\varphi$ is an **isomorphism** between $(B,\oplus,\cdot)$ and $(L,\lor,\land)$.

Does this prove that $B$ equipped with $\oplus$ and $\cdot$ is a Boolean algebra?

**Update:** As for **negation**, we might need to introduce a unary operation $(\bullet)^*$ on $B$, s.t. $1^*=0$ and $0^*=1$, which is isomoprhic to $\neg$ on $L$ for the proof to be complete.

Also: $a \oplus b:=a+b-ab$

Comment: Usually boolean algebras also have $\lnot$ operation, but other than that your isomorphism fixes both operations, so yes, their properties are satisfied.

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean here?  If it is the usual addition modulo $2$, then clearly $\varphi(a\oplus b)=\varphi(a)\vee \varphi(b)$ is false.

Comment: @Zvi You're right. Let's then define $\oplus$ as:
$$
a \oplus b := a+b-ab
$$